# Empty context-sensitive language independent of ZFC?

Tags: lo.logic, formal-languages

Is there a simple context-sensitive grammar $G$ such that $L(G)=\emptyset$ is independent of ZFC?

$L(G)$ is the formal language generated by $G$.

Comment: Take any old Turing machine that accepts proofs of inconsistency of ZFC, allow padding and force linear time halting? If you want something nice, I'm guessing you are out of luck

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04343 using this you'll get some thousands of symbols and many rules in the grammar, I don't think anyone golfed this

Comment: @VilleSalo, in fact [Stefan O'Rear golfed it](https://github.com/sorear/metamath-turing-machines); separately, based on a comment of [Joseph Van Name](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22277/joseph-van-name) on Scott Aaronson's blog post about that paper, I've made a [much smaller TM](http://cheddarmonk.org/papers/laver.pdf) whose termination is conjectured to be independent of ZFC.

Comment: Oh, cool, I am out of the loop. So we are under 2000 states

Comment: @VilleSalo I don't understand what you mean by linear time halting. How does that build a context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: CSL is the same as nondeterministic linear space. (I meant to write space but linear time is also linear space so it's ok.)

Comment: Peter: your machine is beautiful (I don't understand it, but aesthetically at least)

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange.

Comment: Does "L=the set of valid ZFC proofs that 1=0" work, under some reasonable encoding scheme?  The context sensitivity is because proof steps can refer back to earlier steps, but that suffices: the space required should be linearly bounded.